# В каждом методе объект BufferedReader Java

Tags: java

В классе много методов, которые предполагают ввод данных. Для этого в каждом методе создаю объект:

```
    BufferedReader bRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
```

Вопрос: как правильно организовывать ввод данных. Сделать

```
  BufferedReader bRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
```

полем класса?

Как это делают не новички?

Пример:

```
   void f1() {
    BufferedReader bRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
   //Вводе диапазонов для поле 1
   //Передача диапазонов в метод для поиска 
   }

   void f2() {
    BufferedReader bRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
   //Вводе диапазонов для поле 2
   //Передача диапазонов в метод для поиска 
   }

   void f3() {
    BufferedReader bRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
   //Вводе диапазонов для поле 3
   //Передача диапазонов в метод для поиска 
   }


   void f4() {
    BufferedReader bRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
   //Выбор сортировки
   //Передача типа сортировки в другой метод  
   }
```

Comment: Вы можете сделать этот объект приватным полем класса. И в конструкторе инициализировать

Comment: опишите задачу, а не решение. использование статических полей и методов обычно говорит о проблемах в архитектуре.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman а при чём тут статические поля? Речь ведь про `private BufferedReader bRead`.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, задача - вопрос: у вас есть 10 методов, в каждом методе предполагается ввод данных с клавиатуры. Как, вы, организуете этот ввод? Выделите объект в поле класса или иначе?

Comment: @Regent *полем класса?* - это статическое поле.

Comment: что делает класс с 10 методами с вводом с клавиатуры?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, Осуществляет поиск элементов из списка по разным полям в разных диапазонах, значение диапазонов вводит пользователь с клавиатуры

Comment: @studentST добавьте пример этого класса в вопрос. Полную реализацию не нужно. Но минимальную структуру хотелось бы увидеть. Вы читали о SOLID?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman это вопрос трактования. В [глоссарии](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/information/glossary.html) говорится, что _field_ - это _A data member of a class. Unless specified otherwise, a field is not static_. И присутствуют термины _instance variable_ и _class variable_, первый из которых считается _field_, а второй - _static field_.

Comment: @Regent я привык считать, что поле класса - это статическое роле. Впрочем вопрос не про это.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, читал.

Comment: @studentST пока похоже, что SRP у вас не соблюдается.

Comment: Что-то так всё и заглохло. В общем, не знаю насчет "не новичков", но чтобы использовать один и тот же `Reader`, можно сохранить его как поле и инициализировать либо в конструкторе (тогда поле можно даже объявить как `final`), либо перед первым использованием.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хорошим вариантом решения вашей задачи, будет создание отдельного объекта, который взаимодействует с пользователем (читает данные и выдает подсказки). У объекта должны быть высокоуровневые методы, такие как получить диапазон поиска, получить тип сортировки и т.д. Затем этот объект вы должны внедрить (inject) в тот объект, которые производить работу с данными.

Такой способ позволит вам:

1. Написать тесты на оба объекта.
2. При необходимости полностью поменять интерфейс взаимодействия с пользователем. Например, сделать графический интерфейс или веб интерфейс.

Примерно такой вариант:

```
public interface HumanInterface {
    SortType getSortType();
    SearchParameters getSearchParameters();
}

public class DoWork {
    private HumanInterface hi;

    public DoWork(HumanInterface hi) {
        this.hi = hi;
    }

    void f1() {
        //Вводе диапазонов для поле 1
        SearchParameters sp = hi.getSearchParameters();
        //Передача диапазонов в метод для поиска 
        doSearch(sp);
    }

    void f4() {
        //Выбор сортировки
        SortType st = hi.getSortType();
        //Передача типа сортировки в другой метод
        doSort(st);
    }

}
```